# How to append head of a list to the tail of same list?

Tags: scala

Example: List(red,blue,green,black).I want to append head of this list to the tail of same list.So after first iteration my list will be List(blue,green,black,red),after that List(green,black,red,blue) and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing it comes to my mind is do what you are just saying, *append the head of the list to the tail*

```
val a = List("red","blue","green","black")
val b = a.tail :+ a.head
```

or to make it safer:

```
//val a = Nil
val a = List("red","blue","green","black")
//val a = List("red")

val b = a match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case h :: t => t :+ h
}

println(b)
```

Comment: How is the second one "safer"? It crashes for `Nil` in exactly the same way as the first one, because `Nil.tail` throws an exception: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list`. It doesn't even compile properly, because it produces a `List[Any]`...

Comment: Oh!, didn't thought of the tail case. Let me update it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Now it should be safe, I think.

Comment: While you are at it, you could at least do `case h :: t => t :+ h` to avoid an extra call to `tail` and `head`.

Comment: But, in that case statement, isn't the `unapply` method calling internally `head` and `tail`?

Comment: Yes, it [does again call `.head` and `.tail`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/package.scala#L70). That's why I wrote [`::`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L576) and not `+:`. I am for some reason pretty certain that pattern matching on case-classes should be a little bit more efficient than calling an extractor method on some unrelated object.